# Core Data - NSFetchedResultsController using NSPredicate

Tags: swift, core-data, fetch, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have Parent entity called **Card** and child entity **CardHistoryItem** with the to-many relationship. I'm trying to fetch histories for my current selected card, but it returns nothing just empty array.

My code:

```
lazy var cardHistoryItemsFRC: NSFetchedResultsController<CardHistoryItem> = {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<CardHistoryItem>(entityName: "CardHistoryItem")
        if let currentCard = self.currentEntity as? Card {
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "card = %@", currentCard)
        }
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        
        let mainContext = CoreDataController.sharedInstance.mainContext
        
        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: mainContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
        frc.delegate = self
        
        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("NSFetchedResultsController perform fetch error!")
        }
        
        return frc
    }()
```

Can someone please help me to find correct predicate?

**Thanks**

Comment: This is not needed, you can access the CardHistoryItem through a property that has the same name as the relationship. So if you named the relationship from Card to CardHistoryItem "cardHistoryItems" then do `let items = currenctCard.cardHistoryItems` to access them. Remember that Core Data is an object mapping framework and not a database.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I did that before, I get currentCard from CoreData and `currenctCard.cardHistoryItems` gives me fault.

Comment: Then you have some other issue because that is the way it should be done.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to find fault reason. Thank You for help! 

Comment: "Fault" is a normal Core Data term, it's not an error. You can still use the property values.

Comment: Yes I read about it from Apple docs. Thanks for suggestion!